# Arranging the vertices based on the number of edges in jung

Tags: java, jung, jung2

I have created a network based on interactions. Some vertices have more interaction and some has less interaction. I have to display the vertex with more interaction at the center of the network and other vertices should lie around the central vertex. How can i proceed with this?
Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If none of the existing layout algorithms do what you want, then you will need to provide your own `Layout` class.

An intermediate option that you might try would be to identify the vertices that have the highest degree, fix[1] their positions in places at the middle of the viewing area that look good to you, and then let the layout algorithm select the positions for the rest of the vertices.

[1] use setLocation() and lock() before you start the layout algorithm: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/AbstractLayout.html#setLocation(V, double, double)

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try with the above.

Comment: Sir i have tried with static Layout. But vertices and edges are Strings. SO how can i set location for my vertices. **Transformer<String, Point2D> locationTransformer = new Transformer<String, Point2D>() {

   @Override
   public Point2D transform(String i) {
    int value = (i * 80) + 20;
    return new Point2D.Double((double) value, (double) value);
   }
  };**

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try.